# Internet access directly through modem, but not through router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, modem

I’m trying to set up a new network at my home and am having issues... in short, I can access the internet through my modem directly, but not through the router. Here is a brief writeup for today's 4 hours of troubleshooting.

Equipment used:

- Comcast Xfinity cable internet (Blast upgrade:  105mbps)
- Motorola SURFboard SB6121 modem
- ASUS RT-AC56U router

Had the new house wired up with Xfinity this morning. Cable guy was here for just over an hour. Modem was registered and hooked up. He plugged it into my PC directly, and the Internet was working very quickly and reliably, with speeds as advertised.

When he left I proceeded to disconnect the modem from the computer, and add the router to the setup. The router is verified working, I’ve been using it as recently as Saturday on the DHL connection back home. Though the wireless network activates and is strong, and appears to connect to the Internet, webpages will not load. Wired connections through the router show the following error:

> Connected: No internet access.

Windows troubleshooting yields the error message

> The remote device or resource won't accept the connection.

I did some research on that error message, and got a lot of minor problems with quick solutions, the most popular being disabling proxy settings, that did not help me. So I moved on to search terms like "Internet through modem not router." This brought up more complicated answers having to do with the modem grabbing the MAC address of the computer instead of the router, or not being able to grab a router address at all. This sounded logical to me so I did some playing with it.

I have tried:

- Different cables
- Resetting and rebooting the router
- Power cycling the modem
- Cloning the MAC address of the PC and assigning it to the router
- Different orders of restarting equipment, hoping the modem would identify with the router

All several times and in different orders, with no luck.

In short, all devices are working, I have internet to the modem, and communication is strong to the router, but no internet access wired or wirelessly.

Not sure where to go from here.  Got any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Here is some additional information.

When I switch from using the modem for connection back to trying the router, I get a network error window stating:

> Windows has detected an IP address conflict. Another computer on this
>   network has the same IP address as this computer.

When running the `ipconfig` while pulling Internet directly from the modem, I get 4 results under DNS Servers:

```
2001:558:feed::2
2001:558:feed::1
162.150.21.49
162.150.8.49
```

When running the `ipconfig` while connected to the router, only one DNS server is listed:

```
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: @JakeGould thank you for your help.  I am trying to follow your detailed instructions from the other thread on resetting the cable modem.  However, when I press "Reset All Defaults" and click OK, nothing happens (no confirmation message or reaction from the modem).  Can you advise?

Comment: @JakeGould it has been several minutes with no reaction from the lights on the modem.  I am looking at the instructions here:

http://www.surfboard.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ARRIS_SURFboard_SB6121_User_Guide.pdf

Which would suggest that perhaps "Restart Cable Modem" is what I'm looking for?

I did try disconnecting the modem for an extended time, and then connecting exclusively to the router, to no avail.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!  I finally got the internet working.  This solution should have worked but for some reason the reset function on the modem UI did not work.  I followed your instructions exactly, but instead of resetting the modem myself, I used XFinity chat and they reset things from their end (I did have to confirm the modem's serial number, MAC address, make and model with the representative).  They instructed me to turn off the modem, they reset it, I waited for one minute, then plugged it back in, but this time, into the router only.  Couldn't have done it without you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're connecting the WAN port of the router (it should be blue on your ASUS RT-AC56U) to the LAN port of the cable modem.

Comment: Also make sure your router's WAN port is configured to obtain its address by DHCP. Also verify the DNS addresses the router obtains as this is why webpages don't load (their names can't be resolved so error out).

Comment: Hi Spiff, yes, I have verified that the WAN port on the router is connected to the LAN port on the modem.

Comment: Hi Big Chris, 

I have verified that the WAN is set up for DHCP.  Any chance you'd be able to walk me through testing your second recommendation?  Not sure how to do this.  Thanks

Comment: Hi Andrew, when replying to someone who wasn't the one who posted the Answer, be sure to @-tag them so they get notified. @BigChris

Comment: @Spiff Is there some reason you're recommending he use a WAN-to-LAN setup? It generally results in double-NAT and causes lots of problems.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz His Motorola SURFboard SB6121 is an actual plain old DOCSIS 3.0 modem, not a gateway. It doesn't do NAT, so double NAT is not a worry here. But like all DOCSIS modems, it latches onto the first MAC address it sees after boot, so he doesn't want it connected to the LAN-side switch of his ASUS router, where it would see all the MAC addresses of all machines on the LAN and possibly latch onto the wrong one. I know it's weird to find a box that's really just a modem nowadays, but the SB6121 is one.

Comment: @Spiff You're right. So your answer is actually wrong, since the modem has no LAN port.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sure it does. Its Ethernet port is its LAN port. Ethernet is a LAN technology, the icon on the port represents a LAN. I suppose you could split hairs and point out that the DOCSIS cable modem standard breaks the LAN nature of Ethernet by creating a weirdly broken Ethernet-like port that only wants to talk to one machine, but I'm not sure that that technical quibble is helpful here.

Comment: Here is some additional information.  (Added to OP as well for formatting purposes)

When I switch from using the modem for connection back to trying the router, I get a network error window stating:  "Windows has detected an IP address conflict.  Another computer on this network has the same IP address as this computer." 

When running the ipconfig while pulling internet directly from the modem, I get 4 results under DNS Servers:

2001:558:feed::2
2001:558:feed::1
162.150.21.49
162.150.8.49

When running the ipconfig while connected to the router, only one DNS server is listed:  

192.168.1.1

Comment: @AndrewPfluger - your router should automatically get some DNS addresses if it's configured to get your WAN by DHCP - well, most are set by the manufacturer to do so - but you can override this and specify your own, for example Google's primary and secondary. It's recommended to use your ISP ones, to start, though. Log in to your router to set these. Read the manual/Google etc.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the comment by @BigChris above, one thing you can try is to make sure the DNS servers are the same when connected directly to the modem as when connected to the router.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Connect your computer to the modem.
2. Ensure internet is accessible.
3. Open a command prompt window, and type `ipconfig /all`.
4. Look for **DNS Servers**, and note what IP addresses are listed there.
5. Connect your computer to the router, and the router to the modem.
6. Open a command prompt window, and type `ipconfig /all`.
7. Compare these DNS server addresses to the previous list.  They should be the same since you are still connected to the same service provider.

There may be websites to help with this test, such as http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/.  Note that I haven't tested these sites...  :-)

For more information on the `ipconfig` command, please see [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ipconfig.mspx?mfr=true).

This test will not solve the problem, but it will confirm that the router sees the same DNS servers as the modem.

Comment: hm. Is this the same person as the original question? If you have two accounts, you can have them merged. if not, well this is a little strange.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, I can understand the confusion.  He's my kid brother.  :-)